# File writing issue with mounted ftp drive with curlftpfs

Tags: linux, ftp, curl, curlftpfs

I have mounted an ftp account to my linux folder using below command

```
curlftpfs -o user=userid:password ip-address /home/temp -o kernel_cache,allow_other,direct_io,umask=0000,uid=1000,gid=1000
```

The problem i am having is whenever I am trying to save data to any file on this mounted folder i.e. any text file it gives "**Input/output error , unable to flush data** " , afterwards the file is created in folder but data is not written to the file

Is there anything i am missing with the command? I am using below curlftpfs version

> curlftpfs 0.9.2 libcurl/7.29.0 fuse/2.9

I also found link below which shows some patch but there seems no documentation on how / where to apply it , any idea how to apply this patch?

> https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=671204

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to mount without any options? 
From provided link suggestion is to mount with default options :
curlftpfs  ftp://userid:password@ip-address /home/temp

Also, **umask=0000** is too open. Try use 0022 or 0002.
Try check **/var/log/messages** or **/var/log/syslog** or **/var/log/kern.log** for some info. "**dmesg**" command may be helpful too.
This depends on distro you are using.

Could you please connect via native ftp-client and upload some files into remote server? May be **userid** has no write permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Just checked the issue was my ftp server was allowing only 1 connection for a user , it seems like for writing it required another connection to be opened increasing limit on ftp server resolved the issue